# É possível remover ou alterar um elemento html e manter seus filhos com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a seguinte estrutura.. gostaria de remover a `div.son` mais manter a `div.grandson`, isso é possível?! ou alterar a sua `<tag>` também seria uma solução.. ex: trocar de `<fieldset>` para uma `<div>`, lembrando que não tenho acesso ao HTML, toda alteração deve ser feita através de **javascript**!

```
<div class="father">
  <fieldset class="son">
    <div class="grandson">//--> Content here</div>
    <div class="grandson">//--> Content here</div>
    <div class="grandson">//--> Content here</div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Tentei utilizar a função `removeChild()` do **javascript**, porem ela remove todo o elemento..

Desde já, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, segue o código:

```js
var father = document.getElementsByClassName('father')[0],
    //grandson = document.getElementsByClassName('grandson'); // descomentar essa linha e comentar a de baixo para resultado interessante
    grandson = document.querySelectorAll('.grandson');

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('son'));
console.log(grandson);

for (var i = 0; i < grandson.length; i++) {
    console.log(grandson[i]);
    father.appendChild(grandson[i]);
}

father.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('son')[0]);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('son'));
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <fieldset class="son">
    <div class="grandson">Content here 1</div>
    <div class="grandson">Content here 2</div>
    <div class="grandson">Content here 3</div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```